# Failed to install matplotlib package

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

I've been trying to install matplotlib package but I end up with this error...
Any help please?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Show requirements, relevant code, output and/or possible error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or by external link.

Answer (score 0):

Try run command from terminal (if you use windows, press Win+R, in showed window type "cmd.exe" and run)
then write your command. try:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

if not workong, try:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

my be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I thank you all for your replies, in fact I had a problem with Pycharm I had to reinstall it in order to get it working.
Seems like I had some contradicting files of some sort...